# How to include image data and boundaries in Post body?

Tags: ruby, image, rest, post, bing

I need to include an image in the body of a Post request using Ruby. The example uses Bing Visual Search API to find images similar to the image sent in the Post body.  I'm getting a result but it's empty JSON. There is evidently something wrong with the code to set up the Post body. I'm new to the Ruby language.

There are text boundaries in the Post body that have to be included with the image data. I know the query works because I can send the same request using C# or Java and get results.  I've tried base64encode the image data and simply reading the file in to the Post array.

```
# include libs
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'
require 'json'
require 'base64'

accessKey = "Access_Key_String"
uri  = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com"
path = "/bing/v7.0/images/visualsearch"
batchNumber = "097ad727-862d-4720-93c4-08f7038cea7c"
fileName = "ElectricBike.jpg"

if accessKey.length != 32 then
    puts "Invalid Bing Search API subscription key!"
    puts "Please paste yours into the source code."
    abort
end

def BuildFormDataStart(batNum, fileName)
    startBoundary = "--batch_" + batNum
    return startBoundary + "\r\n" + "Content-Disposition: form-data; 
    name=\"image\"; filename=" + "\"" + fileName + "\"" + "\r\n\r\n"    
end

def BuildFormDataEnd(batNum)
    return "\r\n\r\n" + "--batch_" + batNum + "--" + "\r\n"
end

# Construct the endpoint uri.
uri = URI(uri + path)

# Load the parts of the post body into an array.
post_body = []

# Add the file Data
post_body << BuildFormDataStart(batchNumber, fileName)

post_body << File.read(fileName) #Base64.encode64(File.read(fileName))

post_body << BuildFormDataEnd(batchNumber)

# Create the HTTP objects
header = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': accessKey}

# Create the request.
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, 'knowledgeRequest' => "KnowledgeRequest")

request['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = accessKey
request.content_type = "multipart/form-data; boundary=batch_" + batchNumber  
request.body = post_body.join


# Send the request and get the response.
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
http.request(request)
end

puts "\nRelevant Headers:\n\n"
response.each_header do |key, value|
    # Header names are lower-cased.
    if key.start_with?("bingapis-") or key.start_with?("x-msedge-") then
        puts key + ": " + value
    end
end

puts "\nJSON Response:\n\n"
puts JSON::pretty_generate(JSON(response.body))
```

## Ruby result is empty, but C# example online works:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-visual-search/quickstarts/csharp

```
  "tags": [
    {
      "displayName": "",
      "actions": [
        {
          "actionType": "MoreSizes"
        },
        {
          "actionType": "ImageById"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "image": {
    "imageInsightsToken": ""
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In reviewing Ruby's `Net::HTTP` class, I found a [reference](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-POST) that says to use `Net::HTTP#post_form` for multipart form data. I'd try refactoring your code to use this method to populate the form body, instead of directly setting it to a string value. It may be that your form data is not being read correctly when the post body is set directly.

Comment: The examples in the reference create the post request and send it in one line of code. There seems to be no way to set headers and add post body.  Without the access key header the request will fail with 401 error.